# How to remove Python 3 warnings for print statements in Pycharm when using the Python 2 interpreter?

Tags: python, pycharm

E.g.:

```
print 'abc'
```

gets highlighted with a message:

```
Python version >= 3.0 do not support this syntax.
```

How to disable that, since I'm on Python 2?

I know about `import __future__` but I don't want to use it now.

I've looked under inspections in the settings, but could not find anything relevant.

The Project Interpreter setting for the project is already 2.7.6, and my programs do run correctly (they wouldn't if the interpreter used to run were python 3).

Pycharm Community Edition 2016.3.1, Ubuntu 14.04, `python` in `PATH` is Python 2.

Comment: I recently saw a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41111702/why-am-i-getting-a-syntax-error-in-python-using-eclipse) about a similar problem in Eclipse, which has a setting for the "interpreter" and a separate setting for "grammar." Could there be a separate option for this in PyCharm as well?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 if it does, I couldn't find it :-)

Comment: From the [link to the interpreter section of the documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41260584/2617068), I get the impression that that's how you set the executable that runs scripts, not necessarily what validation rules it uses when deciding on what warnings to produce. Is it possible to [disable that particular inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html), perhaps?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yeah, I looked into inspections, but could not find the right one. afxentios did :-)

Comment: Figured as much. :) Side note: I was amused to see on that page a warning for "Potentially confusing code constructs - 'with' statement."

Answer (score 13):

I believe what causes this warning is the Editor Inspector and the python version that is set to check.

In Python 2 `print` is statement, but in Python 3 is a function so it requires parenthesis

Go to `Settings > Editor > Inspections`. On the Search Field type `"Code compatibility inspection"` under Python.

Check what python version you have selected on the `Options`. If you have ticked anything else than `2.7`, un-select it and just leave `2.7` as selected.

[image: Editor Inspector Example]

Comment: Argh, that name escaped my "Python 3" queries!

Comment: I have added a screenshot for more clarification.

Comment: @CiroSantilli烏坎事件2016六四事件法轮功 why did you un-mark this respond as an accepted one? I believe it does solve correctly the question.

Comment: It is correct, I'm just going to test if I can get legendary badge with the 2 rep accepts and re-accept later ;-) Anyways, other people will soon upvote you further and it will go up ;-) Sorry for the temporary rep loss.

Comment: OK fair enough ;). Good luck then

Answer (score 1):

What you want is changing the [project interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html)

EDIT:

This looks to be a [bug](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206589935-Python-3-syntax) in older version, try updating to 2016.1.5

Comment: The project interpreter was already 2.7.6 by default. Which explains why programs were running.

Comment: OP already mentioned that they're using the latest version, 2016.3.1.